# Add a unique class to each div inside of a wrapping div

Tags: javascript, twig

I am using twig and JavaScript to create a slideshow, but I need to add a unique css class to each div inside of a wrapping div. The divs inside are all dynamically created  and I can't edit the html. I was hoping to either do this with twig or JavaScript. 
Any help is much appreciated.

For example:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper"> 
 <div>image</div> (These are the divs I need to add a unique css class to)
 <div>image</div>
 <div>image</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some code you tried.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `.slider_wrapper > div` instead of adding a class ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a JavaScript solution (I know nothing of Twig). This should be fairly self-explanatory:

```js
// select divs that are children of the wrapper
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-wrapper > div");

// loop over them
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  // add the unique class using whatever class-naming system you prefer
  divs[i].classList.add("c" + (i+1));
}
```

```css
.c1 { background-color: red; }
.c2 { background-color: green; }
.c3 { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrapper"> 
 <div>image</div>
 <div>image</div>
 <div>image</div>
</div>
```

I've added the c1-3 classes with colours just so that there is something to look at if you click "Run code snippet", but obviously you'd do your own classes.

Note: you had a typo in your html, you need an equals sign after `class`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jquery.

Suppose, you've a html like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

You can add classes to your children like this:

```
let children = $('.parent').children().addClass("hello");
```

Example: [Jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/yicanolari/edit?html,js,output)

(You can do an inspect element to check that `hello` has been added to the child classes)

[image]